# GCP Bucket encryption restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

In GCP we want to encrypt the bucket with customer managed keys. Is there any way we can set a rule where we Cannot create the bucket if the encryption is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an organisation policy, and enforce a policy to force the usage of CMEK (Customer Managed Encryption Key) for some service.

[Here the link](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/cmek-org-policy#example-require-cmek-project) of the example that match your requirement